# Change window.prompt with sweetalert message

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I would like to change the traditional window.prompt window with the similar of sweetalert. But how can i manipulate the input value which i typed in it? Look below:

Here is my part of code:

```
var flag1 = true;

      while (flag1 == true){
        var selection = window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!");
            if ( /^[0-9]+$/.test(selection)) {
            flag1=false;
            }
        }
```

And i want to make it with this one:

```
swal("Write something here:", {
  content: "input",
})
.then((value) => {
  swal(`You typed: ${value}`);
});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You want to replace the `window.prompt` native function? Not a good idea, but you can override it just by saying `window.prompt = function(message) { console.log(message);.... }` etc.

Comment: @ShengSlogar i thought that the variable `value`  has my number that i want. But it seemd that it can't be recognised..

Comment: I misunderstood. Check out the [SweetAlert docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types). Looks like you're missing an `input: 'text'` parameter. Your code should work correctly after. Please post a code example if you have further issues.

Comment: @ShengSlogar thank you for your vulnerable help. yes, like this it works